# Is there any "formula" that allows us make change of variables in surface integrals?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

For example, [here (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) there are some "formulas" (or better stated "theorems") that allows us make change of variables in some integrals. I need an analogous for surface integrals. Could someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the formulae listed in the article?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that by the time you are actually computing a surface integral, you've already parameterized it -- so, you're no longer dealing with an integral over the surface, but rather an integral over a planar region that parameterizes the surface.  So, anything that you could normally do with a double integral (including change of variables) can be done at that point.

For that matter, the standard parameterization formula allows you to choose ANY parameterization -- you can often build a change of variables right in by choosing a smart parameterization of your surface.

Answer (score 1):

If the surface is expressed as a level set $\{x|\phi(x)=c\}$ bounding a solid $\{x|\phi(x)\le c\}$, a change of variables formula can be obtained from the coarea formula
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial c}\int_{\phi(x)\le c} f(x)\,dx = \int_{\phi(x)=c} f(x)\frac{da(x)}{|\nabla\phi(x)|}.$$ 
Make a change of variables $x=p(y)$ in the $dx$ integral, use coarea twice, and write $g=f/|\nabla\phi|$ to make it look better; I find for the surface integral, if I didn't mess up, that
$$ \int_{\phi=c} g\,da = \int_{\phi\circ p=c} g\circ p \frac{|(\nabla\phi)\circ p|}{|\nabla(\phi\circ p)|}\,da.$$

Comment: If I may, could you give me the reference textbooks for the above?

Comment: I learned about the coarea formula in a lecture, and based on that I worked out the change of variables, so I don't have any references. There are some in the Wikipedia article that I haven't looked at.

Comment: What if $|\nabla \phi|=0$ somewhere?

Comment: The Implicit Function Theorem tells you that where $\nabla\phi\ne 0$ , the set $\phi=c$ is locally a smooth surface. So in other cases we are not sure whether the set is a smooth surface and we would have to analyze further whether the surface integrals are defined.